# Is it possible to generate a google sheets document with graphs programmatically as a file?

Tags: google-sheets

I have an application that runs benchmarks and generates a CSV file with the report contents.

To interpret this report, I have created a template GSheets document with queries, drop down selections, graphs, etc.

Consumers must:

- Run the benchmarking tool to generate the data CSV
- Go to the template document in gsheets (outlined in the readme)
- Copy the template into their own gdrive account
- Insert the contents of the CSV into the unprotected data sheet of that document

This is a lot of manual handling and I would rather be able to, like a csv, programmatically produce a file that contains the filled out sheet where the consumer just needs to open the sheet with the Google Sheets account.

From what I can see, Google Sheets doesn't have a specific file format that it uses and the gsheet files are just empty magic links that the web app knows to respond to.

I can imagine that I can use the Google Sheets web API to publish a new file to the user's Google Drive but I don't want to mess around with Google OAuth authentication as I feel that's overkill.

Is it possible to write a file that Google Sheets can interpret directly?

Perhaps I can write an older MS Office .xls file and Google Sheets can interpret it via the import functionality?

My backup is writing the report to an html file with a web app that visualizes the data using some charting JS library - though it would be a shame because everything I need is already in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Google sheets have an API: [gspread](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/).

If it's only a matter of switching data, you could create main spreadsheet with graphs etc. set up, and then using an API copy it and paste new data into it.